# Safari evaluates false if statement

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, safari, try-catch

I am working on a project that i use regex for input formatting.I use lookbehind but safari doesn't support it. So i decided to use different regex for safari. I checked the browser and decide which regex should i use using the code below.

```
const isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
let regexes

if (!isSafari) {
    regexes = {
        numbersAndFirst: /^0*(?=.)|[^\d|,]|(?<=,(.*)),|(?<=,.*0)0*$/g,
    }
} else {
    val = val.split('').reverse().join('')
    regexes = {
        numbersAndFirst: /^0*(?=0.)|[^\d|,]|,(?=(.*),)|(?=.*)0*$/g,
    }
}
```

But when this code block runs, safari throws `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name`. I tried to use `try-catch` but result is same. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I think `if (isSafari) {` will use the one with the lookbehind right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird No, `isSafari` uses negative lookahead.

Comment: If both regexes are supposed to be equivalent, shouldn't you just use the one that's compatible with everything?

Comment: Is a `(?<=` [supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) in Safari?

Comment: @İsmailFurkanGÖKHASAN "*No, isSafari uses negative lookahead.*"  but `(?<=)` is a lookbehind

Comment: @Thefourthbird i have to reverse the string for use safari equalent regex which is not something i want.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Sorry, i forgot to add `!`

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=,(.*))` isn't supported in Safari, see [Can I Use - JS Lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

Answer (score 0):

since my previous answer was deleted with no notification, I'll repost my solution since I had the same problem and I'm sure many people will in the future:
defining the regex with `new RegExp` allows you to catch the error. something like

```
try {
regexes = {
        numbersAndFirst: new RegExp("^0*(?=.)|[^\d|,]|(?<=,(.*)),|(?<=,.*0)0*$","g")
    }
} catch(err) {
// safari alternative here
}
```